# Predict column data types, text qualifier and field terminator

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file which has data in it and is it possible in python to predict the data types of the columns, text qualifier and field terminator of the data in the file?

Comment: What metric would you predict based on? The first few values? Filename?

Comment: First few lines should be the predict metric, like scanning first 1000 lines and predicting it

Comment: that should be fairly straight forward to count up types in a dictionary.  Why don't you give it a go, and then post here if you come across a problem you can't solve with your own research.  In general people here aren't going to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

A file is always a string to python.  If you are assuming that the fields will be `bool`, `int`, etc, and NOT a dictionary or other class, then this is straightforward.  The following could be used once you have a list of the fields from your file.  If you need more complicated checking, then you'd need some sort of custom converter from `string` to the type that you're looking for.

```
def isBool(s):
    return s == 'True' or s == 'False'

def isInt(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def isFloat(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def getType(fields):
    boolCount = 0
    intCount = 0
    floatCount = 0
    # ...

    for field in fields:
        if isBool(field):
            boolCount += 1

        if isInt(field):
            intCount += 1

        if isFloat(field):
            floatCount += 1
        # ...

    if boolCount==len(fields):
        return type(True)
    if intCount ==len(fields):
        return type(1)
    if floatCount == len(fields):
        return type(1.0)
    # ...

    # the default should probably be string
    return type('string')
```

Sample usage:

```
getType(['0','1','2'])           # <class 'int'>
getType(['True','True','False']) # <class 'bool'>
getType(['1.234','1.4123'])      # <class 'float'>
getType(['1','True','1.234'])    # <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess one approach might be to have a list of possible types:

```
TYPES = [float, int, str]
```

Then for each field in each row, try to coerce the field into each type:

```
def guess_type(field):
    for t in TYPES:
        try:
            value = t(field)
            return t
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

Hopefully, if casting to float and int fails, the cast to str should always succeed (because field is a str to begin with.) So you should always get a return value, falling back to str.

It's important that your list of TYPES be in a good order, going from most strict to least strict conversion. By which I mean, an int field (e.g. string "123" could successfully be cast to either an int or a float. You want it to be an int, so try casting to int first. If you get a float field, (e.g. the string "1.23") it will fail to be cast to an int, and will then get cast to a float. So int should be before float in TYPES.

Then, as @wnnmaw suggests, do this for every field in a row. Do that for every row in the (first lines of the) file. Count up the most popular types for each column.